# Access child class constructor from parent class

Tags: dart

I would like to get access to a class constructor from it's parent like;

```
var childClass = Parent().child;
Child child = child.constructor(name, age);
```

Is that possible? Or is there a way to use a class to return a child class to use with constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a "factory constructor":

> Use the factory keyword when implementing a constructor that doesn’t always create a new instance of its class. For example, a factory constructor might return an instance from a cache, **or it might return an instance of a subtype**

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

Example:

```
class Parent {
  factory Parent() {
    return Child();
  }
}
```